# Python multithreading not getting desired performance

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a bunch of pandas dataframe I would like to print out to any format (csv, json, etc) -- and would like to preserve the order, based on the order of the data frames read.  Unfortunately `.to_csv()` can take some time, sometimes 2x longer than just reading the dataframe.

Lets take the image as an example:

[image: time execution]

Here you can see that running the task linearly, reading the data frame, printing it out, then repeat for the remaining data frames.  This can take about 3x longer than just reading the data frame.  Theoretically, if we can push the printing (`to_csv()`) to a separate threads (2 threads, plus the main thread reading), we can achieve an improve performance that could almost be a third of the total execution compared to the linear (synchronous) version.  Of course with just 3 reads, it looks like its just half as fast.  But the more dataframes you read, the faster it will be (theoretically).

Unfortunately, the actual does not work like so.  I am getting a very small gain in performance.  Where the read time is actually taking longer.  This might be due to the fact that the `to_csv()` is CPU extensive, and using all the reasources in the process.  And since it is multithreaded, it all shares the same resources.  Thus not much gains.

So my question is, how can I improve the code to get a performance closer to the theoretical numbers.  I tried using multiprocessing but failed to get a working code.  How can I have this in multiprocessing?  Is there other ways I could improve the total execution time of such a task?

Here's my sample code using multithreads:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
from threading import Thread
import queue
from io import StringIO
from line_profiler import LineProfiler


NUMS = 500
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

HEADERS = ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g\n"
SAMPLE_CSV = HEADERS + "\n".join([f"{x},{x},{x},{x},{x},{x},{x},{x}" for x in range(4000)])


def linear_test():
    print("------Linear Test-------")
    main_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    total_read_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_add_task = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_to_csv_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_to_print = datetime.timedelta(0)

    for x in range(NUMS):

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(SAMPLE_CSV), header=0, index_col=0)
        total_read_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        #
        total_add_task += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        data = df.to_csv()
        total_to_csv_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(data, file=DEVNULL)
        total_to_print += datetime.datetime.now() - start

    print("total_read_time: {}".format(total_read_time))
    print("total_add_task: {}".format(total_add_task))
    print("total_to_csv_time: {}".format(total_to_csv_time))
    print("total_to_print: {}".format(total_to_print))
    print("total: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - main_start))


class Handler():
    def __init__(self, num_workers=1):
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.total_num_jobs = 0
        self.jobs_completed = 0
        self.answers_sent = 0
        self.jobs = queue.Queue()
        self.results = queue.Queue()
        self.start_workers()

    def add_task(self, task, *args, **kwargs):
        args = args or ()
        kwargs = kwargs or {}
        self.total_num_jobs += 1
        self.jobs.put((task, args, kwargs))

    def start_workers(self):
        for i in range(self.num_workers):
            t = Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            item, args, kwargs = self.jobs.get()
            item(*args, **kwargs)
            self.jobs_completed += 1
            self.jobs.task_done()

    def get_answers(self):
        while self.answers_sent < self.total_num_jobs or self.jobs_completed == 0:
            yield self.results.get()
            self.answers_sent += 1
            self.results.task_done()


def task(task_num, df, q):
    ans = df.to_csv()
    q.put((task_num, ans))


def parallel_test():
    print("------Parallel Test-------")
    main_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    total_read_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_add_task = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_to_csv_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    total_to_print = datetime.timedelta(0)
    h = Handler(num_workers=2)
    q = h.results
    answers = {}
    curr_task = 1
    t = 1

    for x in range(NUMS):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(SAMPLE_CSV), header=0, index_col=0)
        total_read_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        h.add_task(task, t, df, q)
        t += 1
        total_add_task += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        #data = df.to_csv()
        total_to_csv_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start

        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        #print(data, file=DEVNULL)
        total_to_print += datetime.datetime.now() - start

    print("total_read_time: {}".format(total_read_time))
    print("total_add_task: {}".format(total_add_task))
    print("total_to_csv_time: {}".format(total_to_csv_time))
    print("total_to_print: {}".format(total_to_print))

    for task_num, ans in h.get_answers():
        #print("got back: {}".format(task_num, ans))
        answers[task_num] = ans
        if curr_task in answers:
            print(answers[curr_task], file=DEVNULL)
            del answers[curr_task]
            curr_task += 1

    # In case others are left out
    for k, v in answers.items():
        print(k)

    h.jobs.join()  # block until all tasks are done

    print("total: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - main_start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # linear_test()
    # parallel_test()

    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(linear_test)
    lp_wrapper()
    lp.print_stats()

    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(parallel_test)
    lp_wrapper()
    lp.print_stats()
```

The output will be below.  Where you can see in the linear test reading the data frame only took 4.6 seconds (42% of the total execution).  But reading the data frames in the parallel test took 9.7 seconds (93% of the total execution):

```
------Linear Test-------
total_read_time: 0:00:04.672765
total_add_task: 0:00:00.001000
total_to_csv_time: 0:00:05.582663
total_to_print: 0:00:00.668319
total: 0:00:10.935723
Timer unit: 1e-07 s

Total time: 10.9309 s
File: ./test.py
Function: linear_test at line 33

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    33                                           def linear_test():
    34         1        225.0    225.0      0.0      print("------Linear Test-------")
    35         1         76.0     76.0      0.0      main_start = datetime.datetime.now()
    36         1         32.0     32.0      0.0      total_read_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    37         1         11.0     11.0      0.0      total_add_task = datetime.timedelta(0)
    38         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      total_to_csv_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
    39         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      total_to_print = datetime.timedelta(0)
    40                                           
    41       501       3374.0      6.7      0.0      for x in range(NUMS):
    42                                           
    43       500       5806.0     11.6      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
    44       500   46728029.0  93456.1     42.7          df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(SAMPLE_CSV), header=0, index_col=0)
    45       500      40199.0     80.4      0.0          total_read_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start
    46                                           
    47       500       6821.0     13.6      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
    48                                                   #
    49       500       6916.0     13.8      0.0          total_add_task += datetime.datetime.now() - start
    50                                           
    51       500       5794.0     11.6      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
    52       500   55843605.0 111687.2     51.1          data = df.to_csv()
    53       500      53640.0    107.3      0.0          total_to_csv_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start
    54                                           
    55       500       6798.0     13.6      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
    56       500    6589129.0  13178.3      6.0          print(data, file=DEVNULL)
    57       500      18258.0     36.5      0.0          total_to_print += datetime.datetime.now() - start
    58                                           
    59         1        221.0    221.0      0.0      print("total_read_time: {}".format(total_read_time))
    60         1         95.0     95.0      0.0      print("total_add_task: {}".format(total_add_task))
    61         1         87.0     87.0      0.0      print("total_to_csv_time: {}".format(total_to_csv_time))
    62         1         85.0     85.0      0.0      print("total_to_print: {}".format(total_to_print))
    63         1        112.0    112.0      0.0      print("total: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - main_start))

------Parallel Test-------
total_read_time: 0:00:09.779954
total_add_task: 0:00:00.016984
total_to_csv_time: 0:00:00.003000
total_to_print: 0:00:00.001001
total: 0:00:10.488563
Timer unit: 1e-07 s

Total time: 10.4803 s
File: ./test.py
Function: parallel_test at line 106

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   106                                           def parallel_test():
   107         1        100.0    100.0      0.0      print("------Parallel Test-------")
   108         1         33.0     33.0      0.0      main_start = datetime.datetime.now()
   109         1         24.0     24.0      0.0      total_read_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
   110         1         10.0     10.0      0.0      total_add_task = datetime.timedelta(0)
   111         1         10.0     10.0      0.0      total_to_csv_time = datetime.timedelta(0)
   112         1         10.0     10.0      0.0      total_to_print = datetime.timedelta(0)
   113         1      13550.0  13550.0      0.0      h = Handler(num_workers=2)
   114         1         15.0     15.0      0.0      q = h.results
   115         1          9.0      9.0      0.0      answers = {}
   116         1          7.0      7.0      0.0      curr_task = 1
   117         1          7.0      7.0      0.0      t = 1
   118                                           
   119       501       5017.0     10.0      0.0      for x in range(NUMS):
   120       500       6545.0     13.1      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
   121       500   97761876.0 195523.8     93.3          df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(SAMPLE_CSV), header=0, index_col=0)
   122       500      45702.0     91.4      0.0          total_read_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start
   123                                           
   124       500       8259.0     16.5      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
   125       500     167269.0    334.5      0.2          h.add_task(task, t, df, q)
   126       500       5009.0     10.0      0.0          t += 1
   127       500      11865.0     23.7      0.0          total_add_task += datetime.datetime.now() - start
   128                                           
   129       500       6949.0     13.9      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
   130                                                   #data = df.to_csv()
   131       500       7921.0     15.8      0.0          total_to_csv_time += datetime.datetime.now() - start
   132                                           
   133       500       6498.0     13.0      0.0          start = datetime.datetime.now()
   134                                                   #print(data, file=DEVNULL)
   135       500       8084.0     16.2      0.0          total_to_print += datetime.datetime.now() - start
   136                                           
   137         1       3321.0   3321.0      0.0      print("total_read_time: {}".format(total_read_time))
   138         1       4669.0   4669.0      0.0      print("total_add_task: {}".format(total_add_task))
   139         1       1995.0   1995.0      0.0      print("total_to_csv_time: {}".format(total_to_csv_time))
   140         1     113037.0 113037.0      0.1      print("total_to_print: {}".format(total_to_print))
   141                                           
   142       501     176106.0    351.5      0.2      for task_num, ans in h.get_answers():
   143                                                   #print("got back: {}".format(task_num, ans))
   144       500       5169.0     10.3      0.0          answers[task_num] = ans
   145       500       4160.0      8.3      0.0          if curr_task in answers:
   146       500    6429159.0  12858.3      6.1              print(answers[curr_task], file=DEVNULL)
   147       500       5646.0     11.3      0.0              del answers[curr_task]
   148       500       4144.0      8.3      0.0              curr_task += 1
   149                                           
   150                                               # In case others are left out
   151         1         24.0     24.0      0.0      for k, v in answers.items():
   152                                                   print(k)
   153                                           
   154         1         61.0     61.0      0.0      h.jobs.join()  # block until all tasks are done
   155                                           
   156         1        328.0    328.0      0.0      print("total: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now() - main_start))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html won't do any good. Read the *CPython implementation detail* paragraph.

Comment: Can you post another metric by replacing `multithreading` with `multiprocessing`? You will only see the benefits of using multithreading in python if you are using some sort of i/o requests because of Gil.

Comment: As i mentioned, i am unable to make it work with multiprocessing, so i cant really have any metrics

Answer (score 0):

Rather than cut your own solution you may want to look at Dask - particularly Dask's Distributed DataFrame if you want to read multiple CSV files into 1 "virtual" big DataFrame *or* Delayed to run functions, as per your example, in parallel across multiple cores. See light examples here if you scroll down: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/

Your other lightweight choice is to use Joblib's `Parallel` interface, this looks exactly like `Delayed` but with much less functionality. I tend to go for Joblib if I want a lightweight solution, then upgrade to Dask if I need more: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html

For both tools if you go down the delayed route - write a function that works in a `for` loop in series (you have this already), then wrap it in the respective delayed syntax and "it should just work". In both cases by default it'll use all the cores on your machine.